# Video Driver for the crespo kernel

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, backlight

I am looking under drivers/video/samsung and I wish to make a custom driver that will specifically handle the screen back light brightness.

So far reading the files **s3cfb_nt35580.c** and **s3cfb_tl2796.c** has shown me how the   functions like  **s5p_bl_update_status** under **s3cfb_tl2796.c** handle screen brightess but the function **update_brightness** is different for **s3cfb_nt35580.c** and **s3cfb_tl2796.c**.

I want to know if these are two different drivers for 2 different drivers for 2 different kernels? for example is one for like crespo and the other for crespo4g or both of them are for the sam kernel.

Also if I am to write a driver of my own. Where should i begin coding it.

Thank you

Comment: If you plan on upstreaming your driver then you should participate in the mailing list for that subsystem.  For now you can just code your driver in that directory and modify the Makefile (and maybe Kconfig) there, too.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that those drivers are for two different lcd configurations. trying to figure out how to make calls to the functions in my driver prog from the kernel